# Representation of a group, and finite index subspaces

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, infinite-groups

Been working on this for a while and haven't gotten anywhere. I would really appreciate some hints.

Let $G$ be a group, not necessarily finite. $V=\mathbb C [G] $ a vector space with basis $(e_g, g\in G)$. 
Let $U\subseteq V$ have basis $(e_{gh}-e_{hg}, g,h\in G)$.

Show that if dim$V/U=n$, then $G$ has exactly $n$ conjugacy classes.

Comment: Let $g_1,\ldots,g_m$ lie in distinct conjugacy classes of $G$.  You should try to prove that $e_{g_1}+U,\ldots,e_{g_m}+U$ are linearly independent, so $m \leq n$.  Then prove that if $g_1,\ldots,g_m$ are a complete set of conjugacy class reps, the $e_{g_i}+U$ span $V/U$ so $n \leq m$.

Comment: It should also help you to observe that $U$ is spanned by $\{e_{ghg^{-1}}-e_h: g,h \in G\}$.